# how to get blackberry db file?

Tags: blackberry, cordova

I used **Phonegap** to create a mobile app with HTML and Javascript files. I could upload my files to **phonegap/apps** to create my app online. I did all things well, but BlackBerry requires a signing key and .db file.  I have signing keys, as I have the **.csi** and **.csj** files.

I tried to get BlackBerry .db file, but **how can I get it?**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply for signing keys here: http://www.blackberry.com/go/codesigning

You will receive an email with attached signing keys. Follow the instructions in the received email to install these keys and use them to sign your application.

Instructions in these emails will guide you to install these signing keys to your development environment. Upon installation of these keys .db file will be created.

If you experience any problems upon installation of your signing keys contact blackberry support team: http://blackberry.com/support